# How to use jquery to attach an onchange (text change) event for a text box for IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, events, browser

I am looking for a way to bind a function to a text box that executes when the text of the text box changed. I want to avoid the use of keyup or keypress, and other similar things. I don't want it to fire when I lose focus of it, just when the text changes. This needs to definitely work in IE browsers, and preferably work in other browsers.

Does anyone know which is the event to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the `change()` handler not work in IE?

Comment: @cfs it does but it only fires on blur!

Comment: what's wrong with `keyup`? (that's almost certainly the correct answer for what you're asking)

Comment: I don't want the keyup events, because they would trigger the function for any key that is pressed like the arrow keys, or the shift key, etc... And the function of the event is it does an ajax request which does server side operations. I want to only do that if the text changed. But I got a workaround, I just set a variable to null, then on the keyup event, I just compare the current text with the variable, and if their different, update the variable and do the function. This way it filters out keys that don't change the text.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to try a setTimeout handler that just checks the value of that textbox every so often and will detect when it changes by comparing the current value to the last value.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you've found a workaround but I just wanted to offer this anyways. Much more granular control.

```
$('#searchbox').on('keyup, keydown, change', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode!= 9 || e.keyCode!= 16 || e.keyCode!= 17 || e.keyCode!= 18){
        //Find keys that you don't want triggering your event and add them in the IF statement above
        //http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

        //Put code here that calls AJAX
    }
});
```